# ListBox change Opacity of unselected items when one is selected

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, listbox, styles

I have a list box with defined DataTemplate, Style and ItemContainerStyle.

This list box have SelectionMode="Single".

Initially all Items have `Opacity="0.7"`, when Item selected I make it `Opacity="1"`

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle> 
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"> 
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7"/>
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Triggers> 
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEventLocked}" Value="False"> 
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
        </DataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers> 
</Style>
```

But I also need make all other (unselected) items with `Opacity="0.2"` until Selected item will be unselected.

In short: [Initial (Opacity=0.7)]->[ItemSelected = {(SelectedItem:Opacity=1), (All Unselected items: Opacity=0.2)}]->[Item Deselected (SelectedItem==null) =(Opasity=0.7)]

Thanks for syggestions and ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger on: Selection being there && not being selected oneself.

This should do:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.7" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                        Value="false" />
                <Condition
                        Binding="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}"
                        Value="1" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.2" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```